# Check constraint in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, check-constraints

Please, I just starting to learn SQL and got stuck. I'm trying to build a database for my test project, I've created some tables, did the relations, defined primary and foreign keys.....all of this in SQL Server 2008 through Visual interface (table design/edit), no statement coding (didn't get there yet, but I will :) ).

I have a column `Tax` in a table called `Orders` and I did my homework and found that it's best to use a `decimal` data type (I used decimal(5, 2)) with a `CHECK` constraint.

So I right clicked the column -> constraints and in expression I typed

```
([TAX] >= (0.00) AND [TAX] <= (100.00))
```

My values exceed the check constraint, I can type 123456.0999 and I get 1234560999 in the table, and if I type 2.5 I get 25..... so a **CHECK CONSTRAINT** is not working what it should???

Please help

---

**EDIT:  Here is the create script off my table**

```
    USE [MyCompany]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Orders]    Script Date: 03/22/2013 11:33:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDateTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Tax] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [Shipping] [decimal](7, 3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Orders_Tax] CHECK  (([Tax]>=(0.0) AND [Tax]<=(100.0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Orders_Tax]
GO
```

Answer (score 10):

Check constraints just work - try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                     TotalAmount DECIMAL(18,2),
                     Tax DECIMAL(5,2) CHECK (Tax >= 0.0 AND Tax <= 100.0)
                    )
```

Now when you try inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(TotalAmount, Tax)
VALUES (100.0, 2.75)     --> works just fine

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(TotalAmount, Tax)
VALUES (200.0, 15.75)   --> works just fine

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(TotalAmount, Tax)
VALUES (300.0, -2.0)
```

> *Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Orders__Tax__164452B1". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.Orders", column 'Tax'.*

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(TotalAmount, Tax)
VALUES (400.0, 200.75)
```

> *Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Orders__Tax__164452B1". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.Orders", column 'Tax'.*

So I'd say - that check constraint **IS** working just fine ...

**Update:**

if you insist on doing this the hard way - using the (rather crappy) visual designer - then you need to define the check constraint here:

[image]

Once I do that, and then I go to `Edit top 200 rows` in SQL Server Management Studio to enter data, and I enter something that violates the check constraint, I get:

[image]

If that doesn't work for you from your client application - then you most likely have a problem **with the client app** - and not with the `CHECK` constraint in SQL Server!

Comment: Sorry I'm still not that skilled to know where to put that code precisely but when I change CONSTRAINT to **([Tax]>=(0.0) AND [Tax]<=(100.0))** I get > Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. This is new....:)

Comment: When I type 5.25 or 2.1 or 0.12 it resets it to 525,21,12 and gives that error, i'm working through the interface(design/edit), saving after each change....:)

Comment: To all, especially Marc_s, a BIG Thank you for the description of the (I agree) CRAPPY WAY, but I'm getting there. I got the TAX column defined like you did, but nothing significant happened.  Then I dropped the table, removed all relations and redid it again the same way you described.  Now I also get the error _INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint_ when I input over 100.0, but when I enter 2.5 or 17.8 it just rounds it up to 25 or 178 (with error of course).  Code from script will follow in an answer!